# How to set the value of checkbox in gift_message to the database

Tags: database, magento2.2, magento2.2.6, checkbox, giftmessage

I have added a **custom checkbox** to my magneto cart page for **gift message**. I want to add value 1 to the gift_message table's "remove_tag" column (which i added) if the checkbox is checked.

**How can i achieve it?**

**Which all files need to be changed?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the screenshot of that custom checkbox which i added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read Magento Dev docs to achieve this.   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html . With this approach you can save data to the db as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But since i am new to this i got more confused on which files i need to change.